# Difficult integration but without using Taylor series

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute:

$$\int \frac{x-t}{1-r\cos 2x}\ dx$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Mathematica* gives:

$$\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{e^{2 i x}
   r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}+1}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{e^{2 i x}
   \left(\sqrt{1-r^2}+1\right)}{r}\right)-2 i x \left(\log \left(1+\frac{r e^{2 i
   x}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}-1}\right)-\log \left(1+\frac{\left(\sqrt{1-r^2}-1\right) e^{2 i
   x}}{r}\right)\right)}{4 \sqrt{1-r^2}}-\frac{i t \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{-1+r e^{2 i
   x}}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}\right)}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}$$

which strongly suggests it will be extremely difficult to perform by hand.